# python dataframe datetime frequency extract 5 from '5S'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using pd.inter_freq(df.index) to know the data frequency. My question is, how to extract the digits from the string.
Code:

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'data':range(0,6)},index=pd.date_range('2022-06-03 00:00:00', '2022-06-03 00:00:25', freq='5s'))
print(pd.infer_freq(xdf.index))
# time frequency
tf = int(pd.infer_freq(xdf.index))
```

Expected output

```
tf = 5
```

Present output:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5S'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to access the `n` property of `freq`.

```
>>> xdf.index.freq.n
5
```

---

To find the most frequent frequency, use `mode`:

```
>>> xdf.index.to_series().diff().dt.seconds.mode()
5
```

Comment: Wow. It is straightforward. I did not know this. In some cases, the data frame is not frequent. I mean, one or two rows may be missing but most of the data is frequent, say 5s. How do we extract in that case?

Comment: Simply elegant solution. I thought of resetting the index, then perform diff() and do histoplot and extract the value with high frequency. You simply performed everything in one line. Simply superb. Nailed it. Thanks a lot for saving my resources.

Comment: One more question: here you used `.seconds`. Suppose the df frequeny is in minutes. Will this convert to seconds as well? I want it to be that way only. Because my df could have minute or hours as frequency. I want to maintain consistency.

Comment: @Mainland yes, it'd be converted to seconds. Appreciate the comments !

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing the output of `pd.infer_freq()`, read the number from the [`DatetimeIndex.freq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.freq.html) directly:

```
>>> pd.infer_freq(xdf.index)
'5S'

>>> xdf.index.freq
<5 * Seconds>

>>> xdf.index.freq.n
5

>>> xdf.index.freq.name
'S'
```

Comment: Wow. It is straightforward. I did not know this. In some cases, the dataframe is not frequent. I mean, one or two rows may be missing but most of the data is frequent, say 5s. How do we extract in that case? In that case, '5S' is most frequent value.